# Render .adoc file in HTML template using asciidoctor

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

My goal is to use asciidoctor to render an html file, including an html template, and an .adoc file that can be easily edited by a non-technical worker. I can currently get the html template to render, but am not sure how I can wire up an adoc file to place text inside of specific tags, i.e. inside of the template divs/paragraphs. 
Currently running this command from terminal:

```
rm assets/templates/about/digitization.html && asciidoctor -a stylesheet! -T 
assets/templates/asciidoc/about/templates/ -o assets/templates/about/digitization.html     
assets/templates/asciidoc/about/digitization.adoc
```

With this command, currently anything inside of digitization.adoc is not showing up (nor do I understand how to get text to render within the correct places in the html template).

Comment: Using ruby asciidoctor? What other techs?

Comment: Just asciidoctor and html are my only concerns in this case; it is a java stack however.

Comment: Are you serving the files from the Java server? You'll want to use asciidoctorj for the java integration. Maybe that will work for you as you can run the rendering through the API and get back the html as a string and place it into the response that way.